# System.DivideByZeroException in UWP

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, uwp, flipview

So, i did some updates to my microsoft visual studio. Previously, my UWP flipview is working perfectly. Basically my Flipview reads images from local pictures library. And now if i run my UWP, this exception appears!

```
System.DivideByZeroException
  HResult=0x80020012
  Message=Attempted to divide by zero.
  Source=TMD_Latest
  StackTrace:
   at TMD_Latest.Views.MainPage.ChangeImage(Object sender, Object o) in C:\Users\alish\source\repos\TMD_Latest\TMD_Latest\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 97



 private void ChangeImage(object sender, object o)
        {

            //Get the number of items in the flip view
            var totalItems = TheFlipView.Items.Count;
            //Figure out the new item's index (the current index plus one, if the next item would be out of range, go back to zero)


//This line below is the exception!
            var newItemIndex = (TheFlipView.SelectedIndex + 1) % totalItems;

            //Set the displayed item's index on the flip view

            TheFlipView.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
        }
```

My xaml:

```
<Grid VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpan="5"
                  VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan="5"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Padding="0 30 20 20"
                   Margin="200,-100,0,10"
                  Background="Transparent">
                <x21:Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <x21:RowDefinition Height="405*"/>
                    <x21:RowDefinition Height="21*"/>
                    <x21:RowDefinition Height="425*"/>
                </x21:Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <FlipView x:Name="TheFlipView"
            SelectionChanged="DisplayedItemChanged" Margin="-235,205.6,30,-1221.6" x21:Grid.Row="2"  >
                    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" >
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Source="{Binding}"
                        Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,-200,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                </FlipView>

            </Grid>
```

Please help :(

Comment: totalItems is equal to 0

Comment: @Abestrad Ya why is it so?

Comment: @Abestrad the totalitems is coming from the pictures library. They're pictures in there

Comment: Set a breakpoint in that line and inspect all the FlipView object.

Comment: @Abestrad Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  APPX4001: Build property AppxBundlePlatforms is not explicitly set and is calculated based on currently building architecture. Use 'Create App Package' wizard or edit project file to set it. TMD_Latest

Comment: @Abestrad When i set breakpoint..

Comment: That warning info is telling you that you can use project->store->create app package to edit/set your AppxBundlePlatforms. But, I would like to know what's the value of items when the breakpoint stops there. is it null?

Comment: @abestrad, it says TheFlipView.SelectedIndex= 0

Comment: Are you using databinding?

Comment: @Abestrad Yes, i've added my xaml codes above. It worked fine before. It's after VS studio updated it became like this

Answer (score 2):

As @Abestrad mentioned, this occurs because the right hand side of the remainder operator is zero. As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#remainder-operator):

> The result of `x % y` is the value produced by `x - (x / y) * y`.
>   If y is zero, a `System.DivideByZeroException` is thrown.

One way to solve this in your case is to just wrap the remainder operator in an `if` condition:

```
if (totalItems > 0)
{
    var newItemIndex = (TheFlipView.SelectedIndex + 1) % totalItems; 

    //Set the displayed item's index on the flip view 
    TheFlipView.SelectedIndex = newItemIndex;
}
```